# Google maps multiple polylines between same latitude and longitude issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

Need help in implementing multiple polylines between same latitude and longitude in map.

I have seen many topics on overlapping of polylines but what i need is draw multiple polylines between same latitude and longitude but not overlapping. They should be separeted by some distance.

Is it possible? As there are many links between two points and we need to represent those links separately to differentiate between type of connectivity between them.

Thanks

Comment: You should show some attempt first before asking for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the midpoint between the two points and then instead of drawing lines between point A and B draw line between point A and the midpoint and from the midpoint to point B. For each line keep moving the midpoint up/down a bit so there is separation between the multiple lines.

Comment: Hi eNVy, will try this out.